How do I remap multi-key sequences to individual keys using Karabiner
I want to remap "F1" key to "cmd + tab" using Karabiner. How should I do. I am really new to this app.

What is the objective of this remapping? cmd+tab invokes App Switcher and focus goes to most recently used app. In order to move to any other app tab key must be pressed. If cmd+tab is kept pressed then app selection moves to rightmost app pretty fast which makes selecting desired app challenging.

@AivarPaalberg I am using AltTab and I set its shortcut to cmd+tab instead of the original MacOs system one. (AltTab doesn't allow us to set only one key as a shortcut. It requires combination key that's why I set to cmd+tab). Anyway, I use cmd+tab to switch the apps so many times a day and I want karabiner to remap F1 to cmd+tab instead. P.S. I don't use mission control because I cannot close the windows right away (not like AltTab)
